# Ag-Grid with Angular 5: expanding/collapsing individual rows

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have a ag-grid which don't have a column with common data for grouping(like country column to group cities). I want to expand and collapse the rows below after clicking a specific row and I don't want the top rows to expand and collapse. Do anyone have idea on how to do this?

Comment: The grouping feature is only in the enterprise-edition. Are you using Ag-Grid enterprise?

Comment: Also please rephrase your question. It is not clear what you are asking. Do you want to expand/collapse rows WITHOUT actually grouping anything by column?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Phil I am not using the Ag-Grid enterprise. Do we need to use the enterprise edition? I am grouping by a column which has the same value only for the few rows. Obviously only those rows has to be grouped.

Comment: @Sam Grouping columns is in the free version, I know. But for grouping rows, yes, you need to get Ag-Grid enterprise or use a very old version of Ag-Grid (I think that old version works only with AngularJS, not Angular 2+).